# GAS Changing color of embedded charts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to change color of a column chart series using google apps script.
Here is the data

```
EBIT    2008    2009        2010
Total   14.4%   18.2%       19%
```

gist of the code:

```
chrt = chrt.modify().asColumnChart().setColors(["#acf","#acf","#acf"]).build();
```

The series color do not change and when I open the Advanced edit panel from the front end it shows this error

> all series on a given axis must be of the same data type

The top row of data as plain text.
Second row is percent.

> Update

I also tried this code and it has no effect on the chart

```
 chrt = chrt.modify().setOption('colors','#ffffff','#ffffff','#ffffff']).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer browsing through the configuration page

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/areachart#configuration-options

```
chrt = chrt.modify().setOption('series',[{'color':'black'},{'color':'red'}]).build();
```